# Attribute 'DisplayTitle' is not a valid attribute of element 'WebPartZone'

Tags: visual-studio, application-pages, web-part-zone

I have a `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone` declared on an application page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone ID="Foo" runat="server" DisplayTitle="Bar">
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Visual Studio 2010 displays the following warning "Message" in the Error List window:

> Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'DisplayTitle' is not a valid attribute of element 'WebPartZone'.

Even though it is: [WebPartZone.DisplayTitle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpartzone.displaytitle%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Has anyone ever had to fix this? There's one of these messages for every page in my project (but only when I have the markup open)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on your link, `DisplayTitle` is Read-only, (get only).

Use `HeaderText` to change the title

Comment: HeaderText, but you're right... and that was dumb... thanks!

Comment: Fixed the typo!